# Make a rotate animation: start and end slowly, but fast in the middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I want to have a spinning animation applied to an element: the rotation should start slowly and then become faster and faster, then it will reach a point from where it will continue to be very fast and then *very slowly* go slower and slower until it will stop.

The graph would look like this:

```
^ Speed
|     ********
|   **        ***
|  *             ****
| *                  ***
| *                     ***
+*-------------------------***-> Time
```

How can I apply this path to the jQuery `animate` function?

Currently I have this:

```js
function spin() {
  var $myElm = $(".myClass");

  function rotate(degrees) {
    $myElm.css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
      '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
      'transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'
    });
  }
  $({
    deg: 0
  }).animate({
    deg: 360 * 40
  }, {
    duration: 7000,
    step: function() {
      var deg = this.deg;
      rotate(deg);
    }
  });
}

spin();
```

```css
.myClass {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

This works but it should have a smoother slowing down. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to use `ease-in-out`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar There's no such easing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [jQuery Easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js) `easeInOutQuart` function ; if `this.deg` : `now` parameter of `step` function is less than `6000` or greater than `8000` , set variable `deg` to `now` divided by `8` , which is an even divisor of `14400` : `360 * 40`

```
 $({
    deg: 0
  }).animate({
    deg: 360 * 40
  }, {
    duration: 7000,
    easing: "easeInOutQuart",
    step: function(now) {
      var deg = now < 6000 || now > 8000 ? now / 8 : now;
      rotate(deg);
    }
  });
```

```js
/*
 * jQuery Easing v1.3 - http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
 *
 * Uses the built in easing capabilities added In jQuery 1.1
 * to offer multiple easing options
 *
 * TERMS OF USE - jQuery Easing
 * 
 * Open source under the BSD License. 
 * 
 * Copyright © 2008 George McGinley Smith
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, 
 * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 * 
 * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of 
 * conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list 
 * of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials 
 * provided with the distribution.
 * 
 * Neither the name of the author nor the names of contributors may be used to endorse 
 * or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY 
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 *  COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 *  EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE
 *  GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED 
 * AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 *  NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED 
 * OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE. 
 *
*/

// t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
jQuery.easing['jswing'] = jQuery.easing['swing'];

jQuery.extend( jQuery.easing,
{
 
 easeInOutQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t + b;
  return -c/2 * ((t-=2)*t*t*t - 2) + b;
 }
});

/*
 *
 * TERMS OF USE - EASING EQUATIONS
 * 
 * Open source under the BSD License. 
 * 
 * Copyright © 2001 Robert Penner
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, 
 * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 * 
 * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of 
 * conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list 
 * of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials 
 * provided with the distribution.
 * 
 * Neither the name of the author nor the names of contributors may be used to endorse 
 * or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY 
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 *  COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 *  EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE
 *  GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED 
 * AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 *  NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED 
 * OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE. 
 *
 */

function spin() {
  var $myElm = $(".myClass");

  function rotate(degrees) {
    
    $myElm.css({
      '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
      '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
      '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
      'transform': 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'
    });
    
    
  }
  
  $({
    deg: 0
  }).animate({
    deg: 360 * 40
  }, {
    duration: 7000,
    easing: "easeInOutQuart",
    step: function(now) {
      var deg = now < 6000 || now > 8000 ? now / 8 : now;
      rotate(deg);
    }
  });
}

spin();
```

```css
.myClass {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer yet. Thanks! How can I make it rotate more in the middle part (that middle and fast spinning step)?

Comment: @IonicăBizău Try adjusting conditions that evaluates `now` to set `deg` ; e.g., substituted `1000` for `6000` , `12000` for `8000` at plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Ln1dbdvGu7APs3SHMrwP

Comment: Yes, I played with that, but couldn't get a smooth transition between the animation states. There should be a solution for it. :)

Comment: @IonicăBizău Initially considered substituting using `css` animation , `@keyframes` for `.animate()` to fine tune portions of animation; e.g.; `20%` - `80%` of `@keyframes` declarations could be required `rotate` speed effect

Comment: @IonicăBizău Version using `css` animation http://plnkr.co/edit/Ln1dbdvGu7APs3SHMrwP?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, the thing I don't get is how to control the slowing down of the animation at the end: it starts to spin perfectly, but I want to stop slowly (currently I stops to quickly).

Comment: @IonicăBizău Try adjusting `cubic-bezier` values , used `(1, 0.0, 0.0, 1)` at http://plnkr.co/edit/Ln1dbdvGu7APs3SHMrwP?p=preview

Comment: @IonicăBizău Try with `cubic-bezier(0,0,0,1)`

Comment: It's not showing the animation for me even I've put the script of jquery lib. and everything, so weird :/

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `ease-in-out` in css transitions. If you want to define a more specific animation, you can try to define your own by using a tool like this one: [ceaser](https://matthewlein.com/ceaser/)

For example:

```
transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.870, 0.025, 0.130, 0.985);
```

Edit: If you want to only use the animate function of jQuery for this, you can try to use the [jQuery easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

```
animate({deg: 360 * 40}, {duration: 1000, easing: 'easeInOutCubic'})
```

See the available easing animation in this cheat sheet : http://easings.net/

Comment: It is possible to defined more than 4 parameters in the `cubic-bezier` thingy?

Comment: No, see [MDN timing function doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function).

Comment: Yeah, saw it. But any ideas how to solve this? Can you post a working example I can test?

Answer (score 2):

You can add in your desired element class and then make an another class like .effect and write css for it in .css file

```
      .effect {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
       -webkit.....
        -moz....
        }
```

and then in your .js file , write under the action or event call function

```
     $("class name you want to add effect to").addClass("effect");
```

Its jquery with some css in your stylesheet

Answer (score 2):

@ Ionică Bizău
you can control animation timing by writing

```
     animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

or if you are using a transition then

```
     transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect..actually animation-timing -function doesnot work without defining a proper animation and keyframes.

Comment: In order to use animation, you would have to rewrite your code for animation..or if you want to have a transition then have a look at my previous answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

Ease-in-out can be used in css transitions and animations , not in transforms.
You should use transitions for that desired effect with ease-in-out in transition-timing-function

Comment: Post the code? How can I control the animation timing?