# Can jQuery be used a module pattern of some kind?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw this blip of code in someFile.js:

```
var someObject = {};

someObject.doWork = function(){
  var innerFunction = function() {
    console.log('innerFunction has been called');
  }

  innerFunction();
}

$(someObject.doWork);
```

This code is a piece of a bundle belonging to a durandal project.  Is this some kind of module pattern?  It appears jQuery is being used to invoke a function.

Is there any reason to do this over the more common IIFE?

```
someObject.doWork = (function(){
  var innerFunction = function() {
    console.log('innerFunction has been called');
  }

  innerFunction();
})();
```

To be clear, in the actual code `someObject` lives in the global namespace.

Comment: @KevinB Ahh, the multiple signatures of [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery). Did not consider that `$()` is also an alias for `.ready()` when initally viewed Question.

Comment: Ah, damnit, i got the two examples mixed up. yeah it's dom ready, my first (deleted) comment was right. `$(function () {})` is a dom ready handler, since `someObject.doWork` contains a function, said function will be called on dom ready.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey i don't see a change that would change my response

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey ah, yeah sorry my current first comment is wrong, i mis-understood. ignore it and read the other :p

Comment: @KevinB Note, also that `this` inside of `doWork` would be `document`, not `someObject` with current `.ready()` implementation; `this` inside of `innerFunction` would be `window` http://plnkr.co/edit/5Vk3tCFXDZv8TNutx13t?p=preview. Perhaps one of the reasons `.ready()` is slated for deprecation  https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot gather a reason to use that particular pattern. No value, nor original object is returned from `.doWork()`. `$(someObject)` is not defined as a variable; at least at`javascript` at Question.

The reason to pass an object to `jQuery()` would be to utilize the jQuery methods on the object, where `this[0]` would be the original object at a callback; e.g.,

```
$(someObject).animate({someObject.property:someObject.property})
```

See [Make a rotate animation: start and end slowly, but fast in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253287/make-a-rotate-animation-start-and-end-slowly-but-fast-in-the-middle)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case `someObject.doWork` is a function.  In the second case (IIFE) `someObject.doWork` is undefined.  I believe the original author intended to create a module, albeit in an unorthodox way.  I plan to refactor the code to use a more recognizable pattern.